# I keep getting a syntax error when using a tuple and if statements

Tags: python, if-statement, pygame, sprite

I created the below code for a pygame sprite:

```
import pygame
from imageloader import *
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, scale, clip):

        self.asset = imageLoader(image, scale, (clip))
        self.image = self.asset
        self.image.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.x = 400
        self.rect.y = 300
                self.velocityX = 0
                self.velocityY = 0
                self.accelerationX = .25
                self.accelerationY = .25

        def update(self):
                #Process Player Input
                controls = self.getPlayerInput()
                angle = self.getShipRotation(controls)
                self.image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.asset, angle)
                #Update the PHysics
                self.updatePhysics()

        def getPlayerInput(self):
                up = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_UP]
                down = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_DOWN]
                left = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_LEFT]
                right = pygame.key.get_pressed() [pygame.K_RIGHT]

                return (up, right, down, left)


        def getShipRotation(self, controls):

                angle = 0
                if controls[0] = 1 and controls[1] = 0 and controls[2] = 0 and controls[3] = 0:
                        angle = 0
                elif controls[0] = 1 and controls[1] = 1 and controls[2] = 0 and controls[3] = 0:
                        angle = 45
                elif controls[0] = 0 and controls[1] = 1 and controls[2] = 0 and controls[3] = 0:
                        angle = 90
                elif controls[0] = 0 and controls[1] = 1 and controls[2] = 1 and controls[3] = 0:
                        angle = 135
                elif controls[0] = 0 and controls[1] = 0 and controls[2] = 1 and controls[3] = 0:
                        angle = 180
                elif controls[0] = 0 and controls[1] = 0 and controls[2] = 1 and controls[3] = 1:
                        angle = 225
                elif controls[0] = 0 and controls[1] = 0 and controls[2] = 0 and controls[3] = 1:
                        angle = 270
                elif controls[0] = 1 and controls[1] = 0 and controls[2] = 0 and controls[3] = 1:
                        angle = 315
                return angle


        def updatePhysics(self):
                self.velocityX += self.accelerationX
                self.velocityY += self.accelerationY
                self.rect.x += self.velocityX
                self.rect.y += self.velocityY
```

I used that class to make and paste an object:

```
import pygame, sys
from gameobjects import *

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    player = Player("images/Hunter1.bmp", 2, (25,1,23,23))
    player.update()
    screen.blit(player.image, (gameObject.rect.x, gameObject.rect.y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Now, when I run the code in the game loop, I get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    from gameobjects import *
  File "/Users/number1son100/Desktop/Pygame game/gameobjects.py", line 50
    if controls[0] = 1 and controls[1] = 0 and controls[2] = 0 and controls[3] = 0:
                  ^
```

So I ask: what syntax error did I make? I can't find my error. I'm new to python and pygame, so did I make a small mistake? What did I do wrong?

Comment: Equality in python is with `==`. Here you are trying to do assign in the if condition.

Comment: answers galore. you just need `==` instead of `=`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `==` for comparisons and `=` for assignments:

```py
if controls[0] == 1 and controls[1] == 0 and controls[2] == 0 and controls[3] == 0:
    angle = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't do assignment in an `if` statement.  It looks as though you are trying to do comparison, however, which uses `==` rather than `=`.

Answer (score -1):

`=` and `==` are not the same thing.

Comment: True, but a bit cryptic for someone who is actually confusing the two.

Comment: Oh I think I get it. So = is assigning a variable and == is comparing and giving a boolean, right?